# object methods vs individual functions

Tags: javascript

object method:

```
num = {
    next : function(){
     return num.val + 1;
    }
}
num.val = 1;
console.log(num.next());
```

Individual Function:

```
function next(x){
    return x+1;
}
num = 1;
console.log(next(num));
```

These are basic illustrations of doing the same thing via object methods and functions. many say object methods are useful for modularity. but i can achieve it with functions too and my experiences always showed functions are simple because methods reduce flexibility of value storing.

can any one illustrate an example or use case of how object methods can be really useful and functions are inefficient in such cases.

Comment: Object method is specially used for Object-Oriented, if your application is not complex you do well with function.

Comment: @elclanrs i wrote it in a hurry my intentions were to show that object methods are not simple compared to functions

Comment: @C-linkNepal can u show a use case where complexity makes object methods better than functions

Answer (score 0):

What if you have two functions with the same name that achieve two different things ? What if you want to encapsulate private data and behavior ?

Let's see an example (this is not a real code to do...):

```
var ArrayList = function() {

    var length;
    var collection;

    function updateLength() {
        // ArrayList.length is, for whatever reason, not the same
        // as collection.length
        length = collection.length + 10;
    }

    this.add = function(element) {
        collection.push(element);
        updateLength();
    };

    this.clear = function() {
        collection = [];
        updateLength();
    };

    this.getCollection = function() {
        return collection;
    };

    this.getLength = function() {
        return length;
    };

    // clear the collection
    this.clear();

};

var Scene = function(canvas, list) {

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.draw = function() {
        // do something useful with "list"
        var collection = list.getCollection();

        // clear the canvas
        this.clear();

        // for each element in the list, write it on the canvas
        for (var i = 0, length = collection.length; i < length; i++)
        {
            context.fillText( collection[i], i*30, i*30);
        }
    };

    this.clear = function() {
        // clear the whole canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
};


var myList = new ArrayList();
console.log(myList.getLength()); // 10

myList.add("a");
myList.add("b");
console.log(myList.getLength()); // 12

myList.clear();
console.log(myList.getLength()); // 10

// you don't have have access to those private variable outside of the object
console.log(myList.length); // undefined
console.log(myList.collection); // undefined

var canvas = document.getElementById('somecanvas');
var myScene = new Scene(canvas, myList);
myScene.draw();
myScene.clear();

// clearing all objects declared
var allObjects = [myList, myScene]
for (var i = 0, length = allObjects.length; i < length; i++)
{
    allObjects[i].clear();
}
```

You can see different things from this code:

- there are 2 methods named `clear`, are they are really different, and I don't want to change their name
- in `ArrayList`, both variables `length` and `collection` are private and not accessible outside of the object
- for some reason I don't want users of my "class" to remove elements from the `collection` in `ArrayList`. You could not handle it if the variable would be public: if it's public, you can't control what others are doing with it
- at the end of the script, I clear all objects available. I do it with a loop, calling the `clear` method on all objects: it's clean and simple. I don't have to remember that for object of type `ArrayList` I have to call function `clearArrayList` and that for object of type `Scene` I have to call `clearScene`
- ...

All of this is what object-oriented programming is designed for (even if my example is not as good as it should be).

They are two different programming paradigms: [Object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and [Procedural programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming). But there are [many more others paradigms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms), such as [Functionnal programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)